# YUI DataTable Button events lost after filtering

Tags: filter, datatable, yui, listener

I'm using a YUI2 DataTable.
Some of the rows of the tables have an icon button that when clicked on will popup additional details for the row.

I'm doing the following to define the panel which gets displayed with the additional information:

```
MyContainer.panel2 = new YAHOO.widget.Panel("popupPanel2", 
   { width:"650px", visible:false, constraintoviewport:true, overflow:"auto"  } ); 
MyContainer.panel2.render(); 
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("showButton2", "click", 
        MyContainer.panel2.show, MyContainer.panel2, true);
```

So, everything works well with that.  Then I added a button that when clicked on filters out some of the rows.

```
MyContainer.oPushButton1.onclick = function onButtonClickp(p_oEvent) 
{
var filter_val = "xxx";
    myDataTable.getDataSource().sendRequest(filter_val,
        {success: myDataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable},myDataTable);
}
```

This filters and redraws the table.  But after doing that, the buttons on the remaining rows that should popup a panel no longer work.
Nothing happens when I click on the buttons.
I'm sure I've done something wrong, but I don't know what.  The buttons and panels with the correct id's still seem to be available on the page.

Do I somehow have to re-enable the listener for the click event after the datatable redraw?  I'm not sure where to look for trying to debug the failed listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by making a call to addListener again after resetting the data for the Datasource.

```
MyContainer.oPushButton1.onclick = function onButtonClickp(p_oEvent) 
{
    var filter_val = "xxx";
    myDataTable.getDataSource().sendRequest(filter_val,
        {success: myDataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable},myDataTable);
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("showButton2", "click", 
    MyContainer.panel2.show, MyContainer.panel2, true); 
}
```